# Godaddy post method api not working in Android mobile while it's working fine in postman

Tags: android, retrofit2, godaddy-api

I am getting strange problem from server. I developed one android application which is live on play store. Before my application working fine and Api's also working fine but now users increase and api's failed. Only post method api not working while get method api working perfectly. I am using retrofit2 and in api post JsonObject.

Comment: Maybe there is a limit in the api or something different is wrong.

Comment: @Bevor limit where? api working fine in postman but not working in retrofit. i think there is no limitation problem.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing? Anything solve this? I think the server is scrubbing post parameters somehow.